# BaseX-Exception (Interrupted) while loading large XML File

Tags: java, tomcat, basex

I am trying to query a large xml-file like this:

```
ClientSession session = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
session.execute(new 
XQuery("doc('path/dataset.xml')")).getBytes());
```

I get the folloing exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.basex.core.BaseXException: Interrupted.
at org.basex.api.client.ClientSession.receive(ClientSession.java:191)
at org.basex.api.client.ClientSession.execute(ClientSession.java:160)
at org.basex.api.client.ClientSession.execute(ClientSession.java:165)
at org.basex.api.client.Session.execute(Session.java:36)
at testing.Main.main(Main.java:124)
```

I tried to increase the java-heapspace as well as the Xmx-value in the
    `basexserver`-script but it did not help.

What else could causing this exception?

Files having the same structure can be loaded. It seems that the dataset is just to big..

Comment: I guess your example code should be stripped down to some code that can be run out of the box (without the relevant imports, without XRFFLoader, etc.). For example, it is not clear what DatabaseConnection.getConnection() is doing. Please have a look at https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-examples/src/main/java/org/basex/examples/server/ServerQueries.java, and think about specifying a ByteArrayOutputStream via setOutputStream instead of converting the String result to bytes.

Comment: Once again: What is DatabaseConnection.getConnection() doing?

Comment: it just returns a `ClientSession`-object... without any modifications. `session.execute(new XQuery("doc('path/dataset.xml')"));` is causing the error

Comment: p.s i am working with BaseX-version 8.5.3

Comment: Did you check the command-line output of your BaseXServer instance? Does it display an OutOfMemory stack trace or something similar?

Comment: I think followind is the relevant log `23:39:51.204  127.0.0.1:40614  user  ERROR  256783.58  Interrupted.
23:35:34.433  127.0.0.1:40614  user  REQUEST  3.62  XQUERY doc('path/dataset.xml')`

Comment: ah.. where can i found the comandline output? i started the instance via terminal.. its open but its nothing there but the starting-info (Server was started (port: 1984).
)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134065/discussion-between-christian-grun-and-jan).